# Login Background Change

Tags: php, html, background

I have a login system that changes the login boxes to the account info once you are logged in. I would like to have a background and boarder around the account info and not the log in boxes. I tried to add a `<div class>` around the `if($session->logged_in)` but it didn't seem to work.

Here is my code for the logged in stuff. I just need help adding a div class around it.

```
<?php
/**
 * User has already logged in, so display relavent links, including
 * a link to the admin center if the user is an administrator.
 */
if ($session->logged_in) { 
    echo "<div class='welcome'><b>" . $session->username . "</b></div>" . "<div class='account'><a href=\"userinfo.php?user=$session->username\">My Account</a></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;" . "<div class='account'><a href=\"useredit.php\">Edit Account</a></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
    if ($session->isAdmin()) {
        echo "<div class='account'><a href=\"admin/admin.php\">Admin Center</a></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    echo "<div class='account'><a href=\"process.php\">Logout</a>]</div>";
} else {
?>
```

Comment: i don't know if you are using some framework that support you use $session->logged_in or  you write it yourself,i suggest you var_dump($session) to see if it is what you what

Comment: Are you using a CMS for your CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure how are you populating the `$session` array as you haven't mentioned whether you're using any CMS or not. I'd first `var_dump($sessions)` and confirm whether the values are actually there.

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like this:

```
if ($session->isAdmin()) {
    echo "<div class='accountArea'>";   
    echo "<div class='account'><a href=\"admin/admin.php\">Admin Center</a></div> &nbsp;&nbsp;";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: That is what I tried, and it gives me an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) in... on the line below (echo "<div class="accountArea">)

Comment: That error is probably because you're missing a semicolon somewhere in there. Double-check and make sure!

Comment: ahh, darn semicolon... gets me every time haha. It is working flawlessly now. Thank you for all your help!